# Why does Ubuntu take so long in first login?

Tags: login

I have been seeing this problem for a long long time in Ubuntu!

Whenever the system (re)boots, the first login (i.e. the time between entering the password and hitting Enter and the desktop appears) is about equal (or sometimes more) than the boot time (i.e., the time the entire booting process takes until the login screen appears).

I haven't seen this behaviour on any other OS!

Why is it so?
Is there something inappropriately set in the system settings?
How to see exactly which process takes how much time in the login process (just as we use `systemd-analyze` for monitoring startup processes and times)?
Is there any workaround to reduce this login time?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't said what release(s) of Ubuntu are you talking about, but use of snaps adds a lag time when first run (which maybe when you first login). This has been written about rather a lot (esp. earlier this year, mostly as a consequence of https://blog.ubuntu.com/2019/03/28/snap-startup-time-improvements)

Comment: I have been noticing this behaviour since 16.04, if I remember it correctly, which is carried on as a legacy till the most recent 19.04. I would like to mention that I have completely removed snapd, so there are no snaps.

Comment: Does `journalctl -b` give some useful information?